# Ошибка в файле разметки

Tags: java, android

В xml файле код:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/perfume_card"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">
```

И Eclipse ругается на строку

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

- `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardElevation' in package 'ru.mystory.text'`

Не могу понять в чем дело. Библиотеки cardview и recyclerview добавил в проект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
android:id="@+id/perfume_card"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
android:layout_marginRight="7dp">
```

Comment: Теперь - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardUseCompatPadding' in package 'ru.mystory.text'

Comment: @Денис, а от чего вы наследуетесь, когда создаете активити?

Comment: Я по этому примеру пишу код http://awesomedevelop.blogspot.com.by/2015/02/recyclerview-android.html застрял на этой ошибке

Comment: удалите все, что начинается с card_view и это полюбому заработает! А с высотой элементов советую разобраться отдельно.